# TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Could anyone advise how to change the sample to numpy.ndarray I am getting the error message TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. The issue appears to when changing the image to grayscale (sample = functional.to_grayscale(sample, num_output_channels=3). I have tried few solution from but none seems to work. Many Thanks

```
import os

import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms, utils
#from torchvision.transforms import Grayscalei
from torchvision.transforms import functional
import pandas as pd
import pdb
import cv2
from cv2 import imread
from cv2 import resize

class CellsDataset(Dataset):
    # a very simple dataset

    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None, return_filenames=False):
        self.root = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.return_filenames = return_filenames
        self.files = [os.path.join(self.root,filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.root)]
        self.files = [path for path in self.files
                      if os.path.isfile(path) and os.path.splitext(path)[1]=='.png']

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        path = self.files[idx]
        #sample = Image.open(path)
        #sample = cv2.imread(path) 
        #sample = cv2.resize(sample, (512, 512))
        img = imread(filename=path)
        sample = resize(src=img, dsize=(1024, 1024))
        sample = functional.to_grayscale(sample, num_output_channels=3)
        #image = cv2.imread(path)
         
        #sample = image.copy()
        # set blue and green channels to 0
        sample[:, :, 0] = 0
        sample[:, :, 1] = 0

        #transform3 = Grayscale(num_output_channels=3)
        #sample = transform3(sample) # convert to a 3 channel grayscale, as it needs to be 3 channel.
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        if self.return_filenames:
            return sample, path
        else:
            return sample

    def duplicate_and_transform(self,transforms):
        currfilelen = self.__len__()
        
        for pind in range(0,currfilelen-1):
            path = self.files[pind]
            sample = Image.open(path)
            samplet = transforms(sample)
            # save the transformed images and save the associated counts:
            newpath = path[:-4]+'trans.png' #path[:-4] is the path without the .png extension.
            samplet.save(newpath,"PNG")
            metadata = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(self.root,'gt.csv'))
            metadata.set_index('filename',inplace=True)
            count = metadata['count'][os.path.split(path)[-1]]
            samplet.save(newpath,"PNG")
            f = open(self.root+'gt_red.csv','a')
            basepath = os.path.basename(path) # strip away the directory list and just get the filename
            f.write(basepath[:-4]+'trans.png,'+str(count)+'\n')
            # return the new file names and add to self.files.
            self.files.append(newpath)
            #pdb.set_trace()
```

Type error

```
    sample = functional.to_grayscale(sample, num_output_channels=3)
  File "/Users/nubstech/opt/anaconda3/envs/Cells_Counting/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 869, in to_grayscale
    raise TypeError('img should be PIL Image. Got {}'.format(type(img)))
TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Huh? You have defined a class nobody ever uses.

Comment: Sorry, which class are you referring to please?

Comment: There's only one in your code - `CellsDataset`. Where is it instantiated?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using this code in another code which does the image training. It get called(DataLoader) Is this an issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure how anyone can help you. You have shown a piece of code that defines a class but creates no objects of that class (so the definition is pointless) and does nothing else, along with an apparently unrelated error message without indicating which line caused it.

Comment: I have included the Type error.

Comment: You are reading the image with `cv2.imread()` aren't you? So you will get a Numpy array because that's what it returns. But it is complaining that it expects a `PIL Image` so it seems likely that you should be either reading a `PIL Image` with `im = Image.open()` or you should convert the Numpy array you have into a `PIL Image` with `PILIm = Image.fromarray(numpyArray)`.

Comment: Thanks for this! I am confused about how to write this code. I would like to read an image then split by channel then apply the grayscale using the functional option. I am not if i am doing it correctly.